# Ruby Devise: Inconsistency in current_user in API controller VS. Pre-existing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise

I'm attempting to access `current_user` from a custom API controller as shown below:

```
class Api::V1::UserProfileController < ApplicationController
    def index
        puts current_user.inspect
    end


    private
    def set_default_format
        request.format = :json
    end
end
```

To give a bit of context. I'm integrating React to an already existing project. I'm attempting to get the current user that is logged in. But this always returns as nil and when `user_signed_in?` method is called, it's always false. However, I'm able to get `current_user` from Users Controller. So I feel as though there is an inconsistency of the session. How can I access `current_user` from the API controller that reflects the state on other controllers?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your UsersController too?

Comment: The thing is that you should not have to do anything at all if Devise is correctly setup. It injects itself as middleware from the routes and its helpers into your ApplicationController. I would make sure your method of testing isn't the problem. Write actual system/integration tests to test your authentication system instead of just relying on manual testing.

Comment: Without an actual example that replicates the issue its impossible to know why its not working as expected - but I doubt the controller is to blame. It could be a cookie related issue if the react app is performing the requests from another domain.